# How to unbind the grid view row click event in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to unbind datagrid row click event,

I have tried a lot using

```js
$.each(gridData, function (index, row) {
            if (row)
            {
                if (row["Islicense"].toString() == "false")
                {                    
                    $('.grid_table tr').each(function () {
                        var ballyDataGridRow = $(this);
                        if (ballyDataGridRow.attr('valuemember') == row["ComponentID"]) {
                            
                           // ballyDataGridRow.find("tr").unbind('click');
                            //ballyDataGridRow.find("tr").undelegate("click");
                           // ballyDataGridRow.find("tr").off("click");
                            //ballyDataGridRow.find('input').prop("disabled", true);
                           
                        }
                    });
                   
                   
                }
            }

        });
```

I have used unbind,undelegate,off, even its not working

Comment: You are trying to `find()` a `tr` inside a `tr`??? That seems very wrong.

Comment: You did try `ballyDataGridRow.unbind('click');` ..right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your `ballyDataGridRow` has had a click attached, then there is no need for the `find('tr')` as that is the `tr` already.

e.g. use this instead

```
ballyDataGridRow.off("click");
```

or

```
ballyDataGridRow.unbind("click");
```

At the moment you are searching for a `tr` within each `tr`, which is like doing this:

```
$('.grid_table tr tr')
```